# How do I register my web service with an Angular Router?

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I have a web service running at `:8000/re/myService`

Before I implemented my router I was able to make my `.get` calls to `myService`

**Get call in service.ts**

```
return await this.http
  .get('/re/myService')
  .toPromise()
  .then(response => response.json().data as MyObject[])
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

However after the folllowing router was implemented. This call gets a 404.

**Error**
[image: Error]

I'm trying to allow the route by adding it to my routes but it doesn't seem to work

**Routes in app.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomePageComponent },
  { path: 'details/:id', component: MyComponent1 },
  { path: 're/myService', redirectTo: '/re/myService', pathMatch:'full'},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
];
```

**The rest of my ngModule**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomePageComponent,
    MyComponent1,
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents(
      [
        ]
    ),
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
  ],
  providers: [AppService,AppDetailsService,{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

How can I add my service path to my routes so I can hit my service correctly?

Comment: From the screenshot, your service seems to be calling port 4200 instead of 8000. I believe 4200 is the default for angular2.

Comment: @demo.b previously(before the router) this was working just fine though. The angular app is running on 4200 and the service on 8000. The web service call would initially make a call to 4200/service and then it would get redirected to 8000

Comment: why do you have a route and a service named the same?

Comment: @pixelbits that was my attempt to fix my problem. I'm removing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the error, it looks like Angular is attempting to execute the call against `localhost:4200` rather than `localhost:8000`. In your `get()`, while in development you'd either need to specify the full path or utilize a proxy intercept/redirect.

If you're using @angular/cli, you can take advantage of [Proxy](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy) to intercept calls to specific path in development mode, and redirect them to a specified target. In PRODUCTION you'd specify the either specify the remote URL of the service endpoint using something like @angular/cli [Environments](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-application-environments) or if the server is loading the static built Angular files, it should resolve accordingly.

You'd create a `proxy.conf.json` with the following contents:

```
{
  "/re/myService": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

You'd then execute your start/serve command as follows to indicate a proxy should be used:

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: That was it! It turns out I had a `proxy.conf.json` defined but I had accidentally deleted my `package.json` which configured it when I would run `npm start`